# send message to public queue of another computer msmq using c#

Tags: c#, msmq

How do I send a message to a public queue of another computer msmq in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a queue name like this:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=OS:machine\queue
```

Where `machine` is the name of the machine and `queue` is the name of the queue. Note that this will bypass all of the Active Directory routing and stuff that MSMQ normally does. Depending on your requirements, that may or may not be OK.